# Inheritace common test steps from base class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, junit

When writing test cases for end-to-end test scenarios using java, selenium, java; we can keep common steps into the base class method and specific add, edit steps in the specific class.

```
public abstract class XXXXBaseTest extends SeleniumTest { 

    @Test
    public void validateCalendarUi() throws IOException {
            **ExpCalendar expCalendar = openExpCalendar();**

            String calenderAvailable = expCalendar.getHeaderViewText();
            Assert.assertEquals(calenderAvailable, "Calendar View", "Failed : Calendar is not available");
    }
}
```

Then, opened `calendar()` method is overridden in each specific class with specific steps.

```
public class XXXXXViewExpirationCalendarTest extends RefDataExpirationCalendarTest {

    @Override
    protected ExpCalendar openExpCalendar() {
        //Here write specific methods
    }

}
```

Is this appropriate approach for test scripting? Can we use inheritance concept to write test cases in this way?

Comment: Please explain me whether this approach is fine.

Comment: Does it do what you expect it to do? Does it allow you to avoid repeating the same code as you expected? Is it easily understandable and readable? If so, don't you have your answer?